# How to launch Skype in HoloLens from Unity through script

Tags: uri, skype, hololens

I have read a question similar to this one, but years ago. I just want to know if there is now an option or some code to put in my Unity app to run Skype from HoloLens. 
I have tried putting the Skype uri by code, but it only works on my PC, not on my HoloLens. It just exit my App and I have to open Skype manually, so it is not the thing I really want.
Anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open up or run Skype from within your own app. It works on your Desktop because that Skype is the full release version. The Skype app that is on the HoloLens is essentially just a beta version and doesn't contain all the features and the Skype URI would be one of the features that it doesn't have.

The only workaround there currently is, is to invoke Cortana to do it for you since you can do that through scripting and it basically is what you described as what you don't want to do.

Sorry, currently it is still not possible.