# Integrate Skype in Hololens App

Tags: hololens

Does any body has any idea how to integrate skype call inside a Hololens(UWP) app. Here is one sample app demo from Microsoft. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OWhGiyR4Ns&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Sorry. no, this has been answered multiple times. The Skype for the HoloLens is only a beta application and cannot be opened within another app. UWP or Unity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872429/how-to-launch-skype-in-hololens-from-unity-through-script/49902460#49902460

Comment: The video you see is not a real application only a concept video

Answer (score 1):

There is a new application, Remote Assist, that does exactly what you describe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-microsoft-remote-assist-app. 
Instead of being tied to Skype, it is integrated to Microsoft Teams, and apart from the new app sharing capability, it's very similar to the old Skype for HoloLens in terms of functionality.